# what is the purpose of -exc, export TERM=dumb in concourse yml file?

Tags: concourse

Can someone tell me what the purpose of `"-exc"`, `"|"`, and `"export TERM=dumb"` in concourse `.yaml` file?

```
 run:
    path: sh
    args:
    - -exc
    - |
      export TERM=dumb
```

Answer (score 3):

The args `-exc` are just arguments to `sh` (which is the [Bourne shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell)), you can read the man pages to learn more about each of them.

The most important of those arguments is `-c`, which allows you to run a command that's passed in as a string for the next argument, which in this case is the line that begins `|\nexport TERM=dumb`.

I'm unsure why anyone would `export TERM=dumb` in a concourse script. It's unnecessary. This might be a relic of someone porting over scripts that were meant to perform CI in docker containers to CI in Concourse.